# Writting messages to shared log file from different MPI processes independently

Tags: parallel-processing, io, mpi, mpi4py

I have a parallel MPI program in which I would like to collect log messages for debugging to a single log text file. The length, number and timing of messages varies for each process and I cannot use the collective write_shared function. Is there a way to check if a process is currently writing to the shared file and hold the others until that action has been completed to prevent messages from being written over on another? I'm imagining functionality like a mutex pr a lock.

Comment: That looks like a bad idea. You can send all the logs to a dedicated process that will print them. Or you can have each rank prepend a timestamp and log to its own file and have a script merge log these files once the MPI job is done.

Comment: Mutexes are for shared memory. MPI has distributed memory. So implementing a mutex is unnecessarily complicated. I would use separate files, and later merge them together if needed.

Comment: Can this help? https://github.com/jrs65/python-mpi-logger